# Linux - Packing structures in kernel space and user space

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I work on the project where I use syscall structures.

**Is structure packing same in kernel space as in user space ?** And I also would like to have some trustworthy source, where I can read more about that.

Example for better understanding:

I receive data about syscall in this structure in kernel space.

```
struct sys_enter_socket_t {
    long unusedParams;
    int __syscall_nr;
    long family;
    long type;
    long protocol;
};
```

I save it to char array and send it to user space. In user space I recast it to this structure and work with it.
Now on my platform it works fine, but I want to be sure, it will work on other platforms.

Comment: Unless the structure has special attributes (e.g. `packed`, `aligned(x)` etc) there shouldn't really be any difference. After all, take a look at the numerous structures shared between kernel and userspace like `struct sockaddr_in`, `struct iovec`, `struct mmsghdr` and so on... they are all defined in the same way in both kernel and userspace programs and compile to the same in-memory layout including padding. If that wasn't the case everything would be broken.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thanks for your response, I just found something about that in kernel documentation

Comment: If the user space copy of the structure is in a char array, it might not be properly aligned to access the members of type `int` or `long` (after recasting). Some architectures will get a SIGBUS signal on unaligned memory access, so watch out for that.

Comment: @Zakys98 I have completely ignored the possibility of different execution modes on the same machine (e.g. 32bit and 64bit programs can live together in x86). In such case you need to take the right choices in order to avoid differences for 32bit vs 64bit programs: either (A) silently differentiate 32bit vs 64bit execution in kernel space making it transparent to the user or (B) design a type that is equivalent in both execution environments (see the answer below) or (C) use different data types for different execution environments (see e.g. [`struct utmp`](https://manned.org/utmp.5)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is structure packing same in kernel space as in user space ?

User-space is about 50 different languages (assembly, C, C++, Pascal, Java, Golang, Ada, MATLAB, ...) each with different rules, sometimes with multiple completely different implementations (e.g. stuff compiled for Windows running under Wine).

Each of these has it's own run-time environment to make it work. For one example, for a function like `readdir()`, the C library might (or might not) get completely different structures from the kernel and convert them into whatever makes sense for however the particular C library felt like defining its `struct dirent`. Note that this is fundamentally a "good thing" - it means that kernel can change its data structures (e.g. add new fields, increase the size of things like timestamps to fix a "year 2038" problem, etc) without breaking everything in user-space.

In other words, kernel developers say "this is specifically how it is for this kernel (in these conditions)" and every different language run-time in user-space does whatever it needs to do hide the lower level stuff so that nothing else (your program's source code) cares what the kernel developers said.

> In user space I recast it to this structure and work with it. Now on my platform it works fine, but I want to be sure, it will work on other platforms.

Compile your program as a 32 bit executable running under a 64-bit kernel; and I think you'll find that (even with the same compiler and linker on the same kernel on the same computer) it does not work.

Specifically; in this case user-space will say that `long` is 32 bits and that no padding is necessary, while kernel will say that `long` is 64 bits and will add 4 bytes of padding after the `int __syscall_nr;`.

To make it easier for different run-time environments to make it work, you could try being explicit, like:

```
struct sys_enter_socket_t {
    uint64_t unusedParams;
    uint32_t __syscall_nr;
    uint32_t reserved;
    uint64_t family;
    uint64_t type;
    uint64_t protocol;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what you are looking for is so called "data model". On x86_64 we use **LP64**, which means **long** and **pointer** are 64 bit in size (**char**, **short** and **int** are assumed 8, 16 and 32 bits correspondingly). On x86 we used **ILP32** which means **integer**, **long** and **pointer** are 32 bits in size (smaller types stay the same - 8 and 16 bits). In both data models **long long** is 64 bits wide.

> Compile your program as a 32 bit executable running under a 64-bit kernel; and I think you'll find that (even with the same compiler and linker on the same kernel on the same computer) it does not work.

This is nice example of how data models work. Thus, "design a type that is equivalent in both execution environments" (as Marco Bonelli put it) using data types with specified size (as Brendan suggested) is a solution.